# WordPress: Overwriting or bypassing redirect rules on custom post types with a URL rewrite

Tags: wordpress, redirect, url-rewriting

-I'm using a number of WordPress rewrite rules to allow for the injection of country-codes immediately at the beginning of the URL path, which are used to determine a timezone offset. An example:

```
add_rewrite_rule('^([A-Za-z]{2})/days/([0-9]+)/?$', 'index.php?geo=$matches[1]&m=$matches[2]&post_type=days','top');
```

This takes a request like www.daysoftheyear.com/days/2011/ (which would usually return all valid content for this request) and allows for, e.g., www.daysoftheyear.com/us/days/2011/ to return the same content but with support for a timezone offset based on the country-code.

This works fine in almost all places, with the exception of a single query type - one for 'days' custom post type pages, e.g., http://www.daysoftheyear.com/days/waffle-day/.

The rules I have in place are:

```
add_rewrite_rule('^([A-Za-z]{2})/?$', 'index.php?geo=$matches[1]','top');
add_rewrite_rule('^([A-Za-z]{2})/days/([0-9]+)/?$', 'index.php?geo=$matches[1]&m=$matches[2]&post_type=days','top');
add_rewrite_rule('^([A-Za-z]{2})/days/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/?$', 'index.php?geo=$matches[1]&m=$matches[2]$matches[3]&post_type=days','top');   
add_rewrite_rule('^([A-Za-z]{2})/days/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/?$', 'index.php?geo=$matches[1]&m=$matches[2]$matches[3]$matches[4]&post_type=days','top');
add_rewrite_rule('^([A-Za-z]{2})/days/([A-Za-z\-].*)/?$', 'index.php?geo=$matches[1]&page=$matches[2]','top');
add_rewrite_rule('^([A-Za-z]{2})/([A-Za-z\-].*)/?$', 'index.php?geo=$matches[1]&pagename=$matches[2]','top');
```

The fifth rule shoud match http://www.daysoftheyear.com/gb/days/waffle-day/ in much the same way as above, but redirects - I suspect that it's confliucting with the inbuilt rules which attempt to redirect to a correct URL if it's malformed (e.g., if I type a close structural match to a correct URL, it'll redirect me to the correct resource).

I can confirm that the 'raw' URL for this request works - e.g., http://www.daysoftheyear.com/index.php?geo=en&name=soup-month&post_type=days returns a valid and expected result.

I'm not convinced this is a regex rule, rather than a specific challenge with the way WP manages custom post types?

**EDIT**

Updated to allow for hyphens - no change in behaviour, though regexpal reports that the regex works against the example URL.

Updated after disabling WP canonical redirects functionality - now 404'ing rather than 301'ing to the page.

Updated to use 'page' rather than 'pagename', based on the information here: http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Post_.26_Page_Parameters - no change in behaviour.

Updated the code, added a linebreak and clarified that I'm actually referencing line 5, rather than line 4.

Comment: In your list of rules you've got 2 calls to `add_rewrite_rule` on line 3 - does that mean the "fourth rule" is the second rule on the third line or the rule on line 4?!

Comment: Typo in pasting, sorry. Have clarified by splitting the double rule onto two lines. I'm referencing then, in fact, line 5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved; it appears that the above ruleset now works correctly - thanks all!

Answer (score 1):

This request `http://www.daysoftheyear.com/days/waffle-day/` won't match your fourth rule since you didn't allow `-` inside the group cature : `([A-Za-z].*)`. Replace this group with `([A-Za-z\-].*)` and it should match.
HTH

Comment: Good spot, thanks! However, this doesn't appear to have solved the problem. Suspect I'm still conflicting with something tied into the redirect-to-canonical logic?